# WearOS hidden permission "usage access" (how to permit?)

Tags: android, permissions, android-jetpack-compose, wear-os, usagestatsmanager

in my jetpack compose wear app I'm trying to get the usage time of the user. I know that I have to `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />` in my manifest.

I also wrote the following code to open the screen where the user can give the needed usage access permission.

```
        val appOps = getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE) as AppOpsManager
        val mode = appOps.checkOpNoThrow("android:get_usage_stats", android.os.Process.myUid(), packageName)
        val granted = mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED

        if (!granted) {
            Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS).apply {
                startActivity(this)
            }
        }
```

On my simulated wearable device the wanted permission screen opens, but on my Galaxy Watch 4 nothing like that opens. I cant even find these permissions manually in the settings (neither on the simulator, nor the real watch).

Can anyone help me out?

Edit: I read a comment that said usage access is not available on wearos, can anyone confirm?
Edit2: The settings app opens, but shows a blackscreen and closes immediately afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/reference/common-intents-31,

this isn't defined as supported on Wear.

> android.settings.USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS
> Handheld, Television, Tablet, Automotive